# Threading in Spidermonkey

Tags: mozilla, nsthread, xpcom, spidermonkey, javascript-engine

I am trying to enable a threaded debug dump in SpiderMonkey, by
editing the jsinterp.cpp file. Basically, the things I am trying to do
are as follows:

1. Catch a JSScript before the main loop of Interpret() begins.
2. Open a separate thread.
3. In that thread, invoke js_Disassemble with the script to get the
   machine code.
4. Write the machine code to a file.

The reason for trying a threaded version is simply for performance
issues. Some addons become "unresponsive" if I run the disassmeble and
write the output in the same thread. I can get some output in a single
thread but it's way too slow.

I followed the tutorial in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Making_Cross-Thread_Calls_Using_Runnables 
for creating threads. But when I built it, I faced 11 "unresolved
external symbol error." Again after some googling, I found out about
setting XPCOM_GLUE by #define XPCOM_GLUE 1. However, this time I am
facing a new problem: "base class nsRunnable not defined". I can't
find a solution for this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely use a separate thread for this. Garbage collection could run on the main thread and collect the `JSScript` out from under you. Then the process would crash.

`js_Interpret` is called every time SpiderMonkey enters the interpreter, whether the browser is running a `<script>` or just calling a function or an `onclick=` event listener. So you probably end up dumping the same scripts many times. Maybe that's why it's so slow. Consider dumping the bytecode at compile time instead.